# Sum of BigDecimals ended up being Integer [Ruby on Rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, decimal

I have recently encountered a problem where the sum of big decimals don't return a big decimal, but instead an integer.

```rb
sig { returns(BigDecimal) }
def period_hours
  @applicable_items.sum { |payroll_item| payroll_item.hours_worked.to_d }
end
```

Where `@applicable_items` return an array of `PayrollItem`.

The error that I got:

```
Return value: Expected type BigDecimal, got type Integer with value 0
```

Also, RubyMine also gives a warning that the return type is not compatible:

```
Incompatible types
Required:
BigDecimal
Returned:
Integer
```

I think I can easily get away by adding `to_d` at the end like this:

```
@applicable_items.sum { |payroll_item| payroll_item.hours_worked.to_d }.to_d
```

But still, I am just curious to know why this could possibly return `Integer` instead of `BigDecimal` while all the values of the sum are already converted using `to_d`.

Thank you so much!

Comment: There is no method to_d for BigDecimal with the latest ruby - what are you using and where does to_d come from, maybe use source_location to find out.

Comment: Rails adds it back in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
irb(main):003:0> [].sum &:to_d
=> 0
```